# Can we use 'gets' when something is not ready but cancelled?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have seen a question asking if we can say

> You can pay when the order **gets** ready

and everyone said that 'is' should be used. My question is can we use 'cancelled' and make it passive?

> You don't need to pay when the order **gets** cancelled (by us).

Also what if I say

> You can pay when the order **gets** ready by us.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Idiomatically, a *person* can **get ready** (i.e. for something), but an *order* cannot.

Confusingly, both a person *and* an order can *be* ready, but the person is ready because *they* prepared *themselves*, while an order is ready because *someone or something* prepared it.

As such:

> You can pay when the order **gets** ready
>
> > **No**, use **is**: *"You can pay when the order **is** ready."*
> >
> > **Alternatively:**, *"You don't need to pay until the order **is** ready."*

---

> You don't need to pay when the order **gets** cancelled (by us).
>
> > **Yes**, although I would use **if** instead of **when**: *"You don't need to pay **if** the order **gets** cancelled (by us)."*  **When** implies that cancellation is the normal state, while **if** implies that this is an abnormal state.
> >
> > **Alternatively:**  *"You don't need to pay if we cancel the order."*

---

> You can pay when the order **gets** ready by us.
>
> > **No**, this just reads wrong.  You *might* say *"You can pay once we have **got** the order **ready**,"* but this is still a little awkward to my eyes.
> >
> > **Alternatively:** *"You don't need to pay until the order is ready."* (again)

Answer (score 1):

In the second expression "gets" can be used. However "gets" can't be used in the third example.

There is a problem with the use of "when" in the second example. It suggests you strongly believe that the order will be cancelled; this seems unlikely. Use "if" instead.

The last sentence is wrong. "get ready" is a phrase. It means "prepare oneself", and doesn't have an object. You can't say "I get ready the order".  You can say "I get ready for work".  It would be possible to say "I get the order ready", so  "You can pay when the order has been gotten ready by us." is grammatically correct. However, it is a horrid, unnecessary and ugly use of the get passive.

A natural way of expressing this is:

> You don't need to pay until the order is ready.

Comment: Eight seconds!! :-)